# How to clear other tabs backstack?

Tags: android

I have four tabs in a TabActivity.  Under each tab an activity is launched and in each activity several fragments are launched. When some event occurs on one tab,  I want to clear other tabs backstack.  So that when user comes to remaining tabs, fragments are launched again.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thinking, found solution to my problem. The  first solution  that I thought is  as
I can get the fragment mangers of  other tabs and pop all the fragments . But when I  was tried to run that , It gives an exception i.e, IllegalStateException because launching a new activity calls onSaveInstance () of that activity. After calling of that, u are not allowed to modify the backstack content of that activity. So I found another solution.

As u are launching an activity under each tab, If some event occurs on other tab remove the other  tabs activities from local activity manager of TabActivity. So that when u go to the remaining tabs, it tries to find those activities from LocalActivityManager.  As we removed those activites, they did not get those activites from manager. Hence it launches the activities again.  It gives the behavior of clearing back stack.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the following flag to the activity

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

this flag will kill the activity and launch it again when you press on Tabspec again